# Learning to drive in Israel

Tags: driving-license, driving, israel

How does one go about learning for a "driving theory" test in Israel (MIVCHAN THEORIA)?

Are there any government-approved books in English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tough one, seems like there is [a book](https://www.agora.co.il/showPhoto.asp?id=1659690) but I couldn't find online anyone selling it.

I found [this site](https://www.lamed.co.il/index.php?clang=eng) that teaches in English.

This is [the official question bank](http://tqen.mot.gov.il) but it doesn't load for me, [try an older snapshot at the web archive site](https://web.archive.org/web/20190504232751/http://tqen.mot.gov.il/)

Finally you can find more information at [kolzchut](https://www.kolzchut.org.il/en/Theory_Test_Accommodations_at_the_Ministry_of_Vehicle_Licensing_(Misrad_HaRishui))

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the Israeli Ministry of Transport publishes a complete (whatever that means) [pool of driving-theory questions and answers](https://www.gov.il/en/departments/dynamiccollectors/theoryexamhe_data?skip=0)!

Other resources:

- Remember there are [different kinds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_licence_in_Israel) of licenses. The typical common is B - private vehicles up to a certain tonnage - but the "theory exam" and/or procedure may be different for different license categories.
- You should first consider the possibility of getting a license on the basis of your foreign driver's license - without going through a "driving theory" exam. See [this website](https://www.nbn.org.il/aliyahpedia/government-services/drivers-license-cars/converting-foreign-drivers-license/) for information about that. On the other hand, it might be worthwhile to actually take lessons:

  > ... So here’s what I realized.  I’m a great driver in the US.  I wasn’t a great driver in Israel.  Neither are most of the people who move here.  I had to get my ego out of the way and realize there were things I objectively needed to learn if I wanted to be as good a driver in Israel as I was in the States.

  (quote is from [here](http://avivahwerner.com/2014/05/15/pass-israeli-drivers-license-exam-first-try/))
- You may also benefit from these on-line practice resources, all in English:

  - [practice-question generator](http://isradrive.com/)
  - [simulator for a complete test](http://testil.com/entest/)
  - [Question & Answer bank](https://www.meteoria.co.il/en)
- Remember that traffic legislation is occasionally tweaked! ... in particular, new traffic signs are promulgated and older ones become deprecated. Material from, say, 10 years ago may be slightly outdated.